# How to get spanned text from huge amount of text?

Tags: android, html

I have amount of text where some parts of it spanned.How can I extract only spanned text from it?

Comment: In your question, you mention the word "huge". How huge is it?

Comment: @Sherif elKhatib:there are 2000 characters..

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=Spanned.getSpans+example&btnG=&client=ms-opera-mini-android&channel=new&gws_rd=cr